# SurfaceView and Menu created

Tags: android, android-widget

It seems that android Menu doesn't work on SurfaceView.  Menu cannot
render when the view is the SurfaceView.

Anybody have the same problems ?

Thank you~~

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine. See the built-in Camera application, or the Act1 video player app, or the Howcast.com video player.